# Secure connection to mysql with SSL using BasicDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datasource

I'm attempting to secure MySQL connections in my application with SSL. The relevant code I have as of now:

```
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUsername(connectorConfig.getUser());
    dataSource.setPassword(connectorConfig.getPassword());
    String uri = connectorConfig.getConnectURI();
    dataSource.setUrl(uri);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(getValidationQuery());
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    datasource.setDriverClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    datasource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Users/xx/xx/client.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "xx");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/Users/xx/xx/server.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xx");

    final DBI dbi = new DBI(datasource);
```

I'm using the [DBCP2 BasicDataSource](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.1.1/index.html) for datasource management and [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/) for executing queries.
However, the above code does not work as I get the following error while attempting to establish connection to the mysql server:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any thoughts on how do I go about providing the SSL context parameters to the MySQL server in this case?

PS: I believe that my SSL configuration is correct as I was able to connect to the MySQL server using the client keystore from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the server's certificate in your truststore, but first check it's not already there with a keytool command.
If it's still not working, use the debug property ( -Djavax.net.debug=all ) then we will check in the output what truststore you're really using, and what certificates are exchanged.

Comment: server.jks already has the server certificate. Using the debug mode, I could see that it ignores the truststore specified in the code and looks in this path instead: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that `System.setProperty` is not the right approach to provide the parameters in my usecase. Switched `BasicDataSource` with `MysqlDataSource` which provides a way to specify the keystore params using `setClientCertificateXX()` and `setTrustCertificateXX()` methods and it seems to be working now.